# Blocking an external ip address with a draytek router

Tags: router, firewall, ip-address, draytek

I have a draytek 2830n router in behind the router supplied from my ISP. Lan1 of the ISP router is connected to VLAN2 port of the draytek router.

I am trying to block an individual IP address using the filter setup feature.

I have tried the following configuration and yet the IP address is not been blocked. What am I doing wrong?

Direction: WAN->LAN/RT/VPN
Source IP: {IP I want to block}
Destination IP: Any
Filter: Block Immediately

Firewall Rule Image:

[image]

Comment: What kind of connection do you have? What are the "direction" options? My guess is your connectiin uses ppp and thus the data arriving on the wan port  is obfusicated.

Comment: Thanks @davidgo Connection is set to dhcp client. Access mode is "static or dynamic ip". The options for this setting are PPPoE or PPTP/L2TP. The other direction options are LAN/RT/VPN -> WAN and LAN/RT/VPN -> LAN/RT/VPN. Any way not to have the external IP address obfusicated?

Comment: I've written a response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your connection type it is impossible to provide an exact answer, however it appears your connection is using some kind of tunnel - this means that the apparent interface of the traffic is not the WAN Interface.

If you try PPPoE setting rather then WAN, and if that fails, PPTP/L2TP that should do it.

Effectively the PPoE or PPTP interface is a virtual Interface where the external IP address of the source won't be obfusicated.

(Think of the PPPoE or PPTP Interface as a VPN between your ISP and yourself - the WAN Interface is seeing the encrypted traffic while the virtual interface on the router which represents the endpoint provides the unencrypted data)